# Select2 - using link in maximum options limit message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, select2-rails

So I only want my users to be able to choose 3 options, before they get a message directing them to the upgrade page.

I have been successful in displaying the message with the link however, the user is unable to click on it. The only way to reach that page is by right clicking and opening in a new tab/window.

Javascript:

```
$(".js-source-states-2").select2({
  maximumSelectionSize: 3,
  formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) {

  // Callback

  return 'You can only select 3 items (Upgrade to <a target="_blank" href="/charges/new">Premium</a>)';
  },
  placeholder: "Select Condition(s)"
});
```

Works as I thought it might:

However the link is un-clickable, even though the cursor changes to allow you to click once you hover above it and the link appears in the bottom left corner of the browser.

[Image of output of the above code, however not able to click the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgAnV.png)

Comment: For now, I have just made the PREMIUM text bold, so that a user will not be confused as to why they cant click a link.

Comment: My guess would be that Select2 is catching the click-events in its' container for custom processing. Select2 can get pretty complex. Could you make an jsFiddle or CodePen example? It would be much easier to try and fix.

Comment: I will make a jsfiddle and update the post when I get back home to my laptop. Thanks for suggesting what could possibly be happening.